# How to hide select option in Internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have tried all of solutions found on the internet, but nothing works. Note that I do not want to remove the options, since the process of generating the select box is complex.

Comment: can you share some code ? something you have tried ? a snippet ? also be more specific about what you want

Comment: @MihaiT I've tried `.attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide();` `.css('display', 'none'); ` and something alike, what I want to accomplish is as simple as to remove space of the hidden option from the select box if it is not visible